# Youtube ID JSON Integration

Tags: android, youtube-api, jsonparser

Hello can some one please explain me the below code of video id of Youtube integration android Json for Video ID.

```
String videoID = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.getJSONArray("items").get(0)).get("id")).get("videoId");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a one liner using java's object casting. 
Instead of using the specific functions `getJSONObject` / `getJSONArray` / `getString`, is it only using `get` + type casting.

An easier (and longer) version would be:

```
// Get the items array from the json object
JSONArray  items = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items")  // equivalent of (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("item")

// Get the first item at index 0
JSONObject item0 = items.getJSONObject(0)  // equivalent of (JSONObject) items.get(0)

// Get the object "id" from the first item
JSONObject idObj = item0.getJSONObject("id") // equivalent of (JSONObject) item0.get("id")

// Get the string video from the object "id"
String videoId   = idObj.getString("videoId") // equivalent of (String) idObj.get("videoId")
```

Or a one line :

```
String videoId = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items")
                           .getJSONObject(0)
                           .getJSONObject("id")
                           .getString("videoId")
```

Comment: why did u use getJSONObject(0) what does that mean

Comment: This means that I am taking the first (index 0) json object from the array items.

Comment: But why we need to take this here us my Json "items":[
{
"kind":"youtube#searchResult",
"etag":"\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/ntqLMg1RGep_vRnftp0HW7Xx7S4\"",
"id":{
"kind":"youtube#video",
"videoId":"Z326AK8vFNw"
},

Comment: You want to take the item 0 only if you are interested on the first video returned from the search.

Comment: How can i get all video id where u have given like .getJsonObject(0) . i have used for loop like     String videoID = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.getJSONArray("items").get(i)).get("id")).get("videoId");